# Having trouble accessing required info through array object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object

[image: Picture of what i want to access]

[A more detailed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3O4H.png)

I am trying to access platform.name for all the parent_platforms however i am getting a bunch of commas in return. I am pretty sure i am supposed to use the .map function to iterate through all platform.name in the parent_platform. Basically my desired output would be names of all the platforms like this PC, PlayStation, Xbox
Here is my current code so far. Thanks

```
function showGames(game)
{
  game.forEach(game => {
    console.log(game);
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');
    card.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-top">
      <img src="${game.background_image}" alt="" class="card-image">
    </div>
    <div class="card-bottom">
      <h1>${game.name}</h1>
      <h3>Release date: ${game.released}</h3>
      <p>Platforms: ${game.parent_platforms.map(platform => platform.name)}</p>
      <p>Rating: ${game.rating}</p>
    </div>
    `;
    main.appendChild(card);
  })
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the text of your image, rather than the image itself.

Comment: I think you've confused things by using the same variable `game` for the original array and the iteration variable in `forEach()`.

Comment: But `game.background_image` doesn't make sense for either of them.

Comment: Oh i see sorry about that i  will change it.

Comment: game.background_image works fine since with game. i am accessing the object and the background_image is what contains the image link

Comment: Ah, it's another property at the same level as `parent_platforms`, but you didn't show it. In that case I can't see why you're not getting what you expect.

Comment: Interesting that you are seeing "a bunch of commas".  This implies an array of whitespace.

Comment: What do you see if you just do `console.log(game.parent_platforms.map(platform => platform.name);`

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Could something be modifying the `game` array asynchronously?

Comment: Also try `console.log(JSON.stringify(game.parent_platforms))`

Comment: I get an array with correct number of items but they are undefined

Comment: This is what i get if i log json.stringify [{"platform":{"id":1,"name":"PC","slug":"pc"}},{"platform":{"id":2,"name":"PlayStation","slug":"playstation"}},{"platform":{"id":3,"name":"Xbox","slug":"xbox"}}]

Comment: @LeeTaylor The code in the picture is for illustration of what i am accessing and does not need to be changed. Also in the picture it is better structured than if i was to type it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what needs to be mapped...

```
[{"platform":{"id":1,"name":"PC","slug":"pc"}},{"platform":{"id":2,"name":"PlayStation","slug":"playstation"}},{"platform":{"id":3,"name":"Xbox","slug":"xbox"}}]
```

and this is the mapping code...

```
game.parent_platforms.map(platform => platform.name)
```

You will certainly get an array of nulls.  There's another level of object nesting there, as follows...

```
game.parent_platforms.map(platform => platform.platform.name)
//                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Bingo! That has solved it. Thank you very much for that. Could you kindly explain why we needed to add another .platform? wasnt the first .platform accessing the items? I have marked your answer as the solution :)

Comment: See my answer, should clarify the nesting

Comment: @CodeItNow, the objects contained in the array each have a single key-value pair, where the key is `platform` and the value is the object you care about `{ name... }`.  The first "platform" is your loop's dummy variable.  `platform.platform` says "the value of the platform key for the object pointed to by my platform dummy variable"

Comment: Ahhhh now it has clicked for me. So the first platform was just a name for the variable we will use in the arrow function. The second .platform was the one accessing the items. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion that names are very important.  (1) consider renaming the game function param to "games" (it's an array, arrays are plural).  The loop variable we just discussed might better be called `platform_container`, and the loop body could say `platform_container.platform.name`.   (admittedly a little wordy, but less apt to confuse the next programmer who sees the code, including yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Your use of map will give an array of the platform names, but what then you'll get a standard array representation (conversion to string) which is unlikely to be what you actually want in the HTML representation.

You might like to try using Array.join, like this:

```
${game.parent_platforms.map(platform => platform.name).join()}
```

This will insert a string formatted such as "PC,PlayStation,Xbox" into the HTML output.  If you want a different separator, add it as an argument to join, thus:

```
${game.parent_platforms.map(platform => platform.name).join(', ')}
```

The structure of the rest of the code is problematic as other commenters have pointed out, but this answers your question as to use of map.

As @danh mentions, there is also a missing level of dereferencing (I'm renaming the parent_platforms element to make it clear):

```
${game.parent_platforms.map(element => element.platform.name).join()}
```

Comment: When an array is converted to a string, it's equivalent to `.join(',')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your code but i am still getting a bunch of commas with spaces now

Comment: Updated to include the additional level of dereferencing highlighted by @danh

Comment: I see! That makes sense. I think i made things more confusing by using same names for various things. Anyways thank you for that @DaveMeehan